# Facebook PHP Canvas App Multiple Site

Tags: facebook, cdn, facebook-php-sdk

At the moment my webserver is in australia serving my Canvas URL.

If I want to add another webserver in the europe and usa to serve the same Canvas URL, what are my options ?

The goal is to minimize the latency between users, facebook server, and my webserver.

The facebook app is implemented in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting webservers by yourself, use [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/), It accelerates your site or app by redistributing and caching your site in worldwide servers, giving faster access to computers outside of Australia. Check this: [With and without Akamai](https://secure.ipage.com/popups/pop-akamai.bml).

Comment: The problem is that I want the cache the PHP app as well.